# Unable to configure launch screen appearance using view controller file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a LaunchScreen.storyboard which serves as the launch screen file. In this storyboard is a view controller with the class LaunchViewController.

In my LaunchViewController.m file I changed the view's background color and added a label with the FB shimmering effect (https://github.com/facebook/Shimmer).

```
_shimmeringView = [[FBShimmeringView alloc] init];
_shimmeringView.shimmering = YES;
_shimmeringView.shimmeringBeginFadeDuration = 0.3;
_shimmeringView.shimmeringOpacity = 0.3;
[self.view addSubview:_shimmeringView];

_logoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:_shimmeringView.bounds];
_logoLabel.text = @"Shimmer";
_logoLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:60.0];
_logoLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_logoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
_logoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_shimmeringView.contentView = _logoLabel;
```

But when I ran it there's only an empty white background displayed as the launch screen. Also I find that he LaunchViewController looks fine when used as a regular view controller. How to make it display the same effect when used as launch screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use code inside a launch view controller nib. Whether it is a storyboard or a separate nib. The code is not executed. The only thing that works is what is in InterfaceBuilder like auto layout and stuff. No code is loaded. This would defeat the purpose of using a launch file. The launcfile is loaded before the app has had chance to load.

No app, no code. Only the launch file.

Answer (score -1):

I've had similar problems, and based on your code, it may be similar to mine. First off, I don't understand your question as much as I would like to. You said, "The LaunchViewController works fine when not used as launch screen." Does that mean that it looks the way you want it to look like when viewing on Xcode, but not on the simulator? I will try to provide possible solutions, and some trouble-shooting tips.

1. It could be something as simple as your background(or something) is at the front of the screen, blocking the rest. If so, you have to reconfigure the order of your items on your launch screen in your xib file in your application.

   2. It could be an error on your part. Some of my programmer friends develop their launch screens using the Xcode interface: I find that easier to use, and it may have less errors.
   3. It could be an issue with the iOS simulator. This is not likely to be true, but it could be. Try running the app on your device and see if it is fine there.

Troubleshooting: In order to trouble shoot your code, comment out your code, and load in all the elements of your launch screen one at a time, checking the iOS simulator and the console in between. You will eventually find the problematic code, and be able to fix it. From looking at your code, I don't see anything wrong (but don't take my word on it, I'm not familiar with coding the launchscreen/storyboard in swift. Good luck, and I hope my tips work.  Also, if your launch screen is appearing fine inside Xcode, it is a programming error or an error on the iOS simulator. A picture or a description of your launch screen could also help future people who will answer this question.

Comment: no I mean everything looks all right when it's used as a regular view controller instead of the launch screen